# Address sanitizer to use with aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1

Tags: cross-compiling, address-sanitizer

When using linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1 toolchain I'm getting an error

```
undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
```

I believe that the cross compiler I use won't support `-fsanitize=address,undefined`.

From "ARM" forums I can see that this issue was fixed only in gcc-arm-8.2-2019.01.

Any idea where to get "asan" package from to get the required shared object cross compiled separately ? Would this method work ?

## MVCE

I am trying to compile the program hello.cpp with debugging symbols and also with address sanitizer below.

```
jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$ cat hello.cpp


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}

jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$
```

```
jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$ /home/jrangab/sandboxes/toolchain/arm/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/work/release/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc "$@" -g -Og -UNDEBUG -rdynamic -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,undefined hello.cpp

jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$ /home/jrangab/sandboxes/toolchain/arm/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/work/release/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find libasan_preinit.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I tried it without the "-fsanitize=address,undefined", you can see that it compiles fine.

```
jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$ /home/jrangab/sandboxes/toolchain/arm/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/work/release/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc "$@" -g -Og -UNDEBUG -rdynamic -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -fno-omit-frame-pointer hello.cpp
```

```
jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$ ls a.out 
a.out
```

```
jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=984dd81fd2a3d078090d3e68d9c1fcb1ca1895cb, with debug_info, not stripped
jrangab@ubuntu:~/sandboxes$
```

Comment: This error may be caused by different reasons, please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @yugr - I have now provided the MVCE. Thanks.